# time taken for execution of a command in mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, time

I want to find out the time taken by mysql to execute a command. When i went through other posts i found this.

> "mysql has a builtin profiler. You can enable profiling by issuing set profiling=1; and use show profiles; to get execution times."

But this is not very effective .pls help.

Comment: try to read stackoverflow rules before posting a question,otherwise your questions may have chance of getting down votes.

Comment: what are stack overflow rules ?

Comment: go through with this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can run query

```
 show processlist
```

while executing your program

Comment: thanks for the suggestion .. even this is not working ... any other method ?